# How to see data in an encrypted realm

Tags: android, encryption, realm

I am using Realm as a database in android application. I want to see data which it holds to debug the issue occurred in one of the devices. The issue is, the database is encrypted with a key. Is there a way to fetch the realm database file from the device and provide the encryption key. That key decrypt the database and allow to query through it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Realm Browser on Mac. It does support opening encrypted files if you have the encryption key as a hex string.

If you are not on a Mac, right now you are unfortunately out of luck, but one work-around is to create a sample app and use the Dynamic Realm API to open it and query it: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms

Comment: Realm browser is now available for windows but i am still not able to view database using my key. i am already closing realm before pulling out of storage. can you help me out?